# I like it, so how do I put a Ring on it?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I know that in order to unlock the later events with the love of my life, I have to give them a Ring. Like everything in Harvest Moon, I gotta create it somehow. How do I make a Ring so that my love knows exactly how I feel about them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rings are accessories, which can be made in the Sewing Studio. The blueprint for the Sewing Studio can purchased for 40,000G from the Silk Country vendor. You'll need 10 Small Lumber, 15 Lumber, 5 Iron, and 5 Wool. Lumber is received from chopping trees, Twigs, and Branches. It can also be purchased from the Carpenter's shop. Iron is found while river diving or from the Safari mining point. Wool can be harvested from Sheep with the Clippers.

To make a Ring, go to the accessories table (it's the one in the middle of the room). There are a number of rings, but the one you're looking for is simply titled "Ring". It requires 1 Silver and 1 Fluorite. Silver can be found while river diving or from the mining point in the Safari, same with Fluorite.

Once you have the Ring, you can start the exchange. There are two ways to go about it, you can do the exchange or you can have your sweetheart do the exchange.

- Direct Exchange - Meet your sweetheart on a Saturday or Sunday. The weather must be sunny and it can't be a festival day. If you have already seen their first two heart events and you're at a Blue flower relationship, give them the Ring.
- Reverse Exchange - Follow the same requirements as above. You must also have the Ring in your rucksack. If you have given them 100+ gifts, then talking to them will start the exchange. For Elise, you need to be at Yellow flower before she'll do the reverse exchange and Raegar will only do the exchange if you talk to him on the first floor of his Restaurant.

Comment: additionally, they will only accept the ring when certain conditions are met, like events being completed, certain flower level, certain day and time. That is usually dependant on your target, though